# NHibernate: Evicting but still having non unique object exception

Tags: nhibernate

This method is not my best, but had a circular reference issue going on so slapped it together last minute. For some reason, even though I'm evicting the original referenced order on the detail object, I've still got another association with the session. Should I use a get instead? Or even better is there a way to say evict ALL orders with ID = x ?

```
public DetailDTO SaveNewDetailToOrder(DetailDTO detailDTO)
    {
        var detailReturn = new DetailDTO();

        try
        {
            var order = LoadOrderById(detailDTO.OrderId);
            var previousStatus = issue.CurrentDetailStatus;

            if (previousStatus != null && detailDTO.Status.Id != previousStatus.Id)
            {
                var detail = Mapper.Map<DetailDTO, Detail>(detailDTO);
                _orderRepository.EvictOrder(detail.DetailOrder);
                order.Details.Add(detailDTO);
                order.IsEscalated = false;
                order.DormantDate = detailDTO.CreatedTime;

                var orderReturn = SaveOrder(order);   ///Error Here
                if (orderReturn.IsActionSuccessful)
                {
                    detailReturn =
                        orderReturn.Details.DTOObjects.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedTime).First();
                    SendStatusChangeEmail(orderReturn);
                }

            }
            else
            {

                detailReturn = _detailService.SaveDetail(detailDTO);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ServiceErrorMessage(ex, detailReturn);
        }

        return detailReturn ;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access session objects and use then whatever you like

```
session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntityEntries
```

but if I were you i would make sure that i'm evicting the right object and spend some time on debuging. Knowing what is going on is better than searching for workarounds

```
foreach (var e in session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntityEntries.Values.OfType<EntityType>().Where(<condition>))
{
    session.Evict(e);
}
```

Comment: "Knowing what is going on is better than searching for workarounds" Absolutely agree, we're past dev cycle on this and in testing. Trying to get it back to the BAs so they can test other features depending on this one while I research.